# Using all Heroku's features through a browser?

Tags: heroku

Is it possible as a developer to set up and manage all the features Heroku provides with nothing but a web browser?

For example, can I make use of everything (including "addons") that has a `heroku` CLI command if I don't have access to a box?

...Once again... for the purpose of this OP, all I have is a web browser!

Comment: u dun necessarily need a *nix machine. windows and mac work just fine

Comment: @SomeshMukherjee please read the entire OP

Comment: u just have a browser isn't exactly useful. What commands are you trying to execute. If you are trying to push something to the repository, stands to reason you need those files on your hard disk. so u need git. we might be able to help if u describe what you want to do instead of saying I want to do everything

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in the comments, you don't need access to Linux or OS X to use the Heroku CLI. If you're on Windows, just [download and use that](https://toolbelt.heroku.com/windows).

The Heroku Dashboard is fairly complete and you can do most app management tasks there. If you don't want to use Git from the command line when pushing code to Heroku, you can use a GUI like the [Git tooling in Visual Studio](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/GitSupportForVisualStudioGitTFSAndVSPutIntoContext.aspx) or [GitHub for Windows](http://windows.github.com/).

Comment: Wow, I guess I was extremely unclear in my OP. I repeat: I only have a browser.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: No, not all.

Long answer: Yes..somewhat.

Heroku provides a web dashboard. And, as the name suggests, it pretty much displays information about your apps. There are, however, some commonly used features in the dashboard to make it easy to maintain an application. For example, Heroku's web dashboard provides the ability to:

1. List all apps
2. Start, stop, scale a process
3. Add/remove access to other users.
4. Add/remove addons. (via the addons.heroku.com website)
5. Creating an new app
6. Selecting an app's region ( while creating the app. I see no way to choose/change it later).

However, you can't do the following:

1. Detailed application logs
2. Listing out availability regions
3. Managing configuration variables (environment variables)
4. Push the app to the heroku repo and deploy it
5. and many more.